# What Is Causing D3 To Not Work Properly In IE10?

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a large codebase and have been cross-browser testing. Everything works, including IE9, except IE10.

It uses D3 to create a timeline with a line for the current date, a line for selected date and rectangles for ranges. The problem is that nothing is being created, I cannot post code since it is so big. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out just as I posted the question.

The latest versions of D3 require .insert to have to parametres, we were just using one. To fix it we have decided to change to .append since it does not change performance and still only has one parameter.

Not sure why only IE10 picks this up though.